# Learning the default browser used on the system

Tags: javascript, node.js, operating-system

I am writing a script file using Node.js, it opens a particular URL in the default browser.

I know how to open a URL in the user's default browser, and it has been asked and answered on Stack overflow before.

But knowing the default browser on the user OS is not discussed.

Is there a way we (developers) can know the default browser used on the user system, knowing that we're running our script in Node.js?

The user might be using Mac os, Windows or any linux distro.

Comment: Maybe use some npm modules? https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-default-browser

Answer (score 1):

The default browser is set at the OS level and registered to perform some task such as opening an `.html` page or a generic *URL*, that means that either you find a way to ask the system *which* is such default browser, or you need a *2 steps verification* procedure:

1. you create a server in any open port (use `0` as port) retrieve such port and point the browser at that `0.0.0.0:port` to detect via User Agent what browser opens pages by default.
2. you store that detail somewhere to be sure the real *URL* you want to show knows what browser is going to land there.

The *store* part is optional, as you can have a bootstrap that does a redirect *after* sniffing the User Agent, think about users switching default browsers among sessions, but this technique should give you a *reasonably good* heuristic to detect the default OS browser to open pages.

The *reasonably good* part is because there are default browsers with randomized User Agent to mitigate further fingerprinting, but I think these cases should be addressed via features detection on the real Web site, or just fail if you don't care about these kind of browsers.

Alternatively, your initial landing page with a redirect **could** do some feature detection to fine-tune and narrow-down the possibility the browser is what you expect, or capable of what you're going to serve in the final site.

---

for history sake ... here two files, a detect to bootstrap and your real site ...

`detect.js`

```js
const server = require('http').createServer((_, res) => {
  res.write(`
    <!doctype html>
    <script>
    const browser = globalThis.chrome ? 'chrome' :
      (globalThis.netscape ? 'firefox' :
        (globalThis.webkit ? 'safari' : 'unknown'));
    document.write(
      '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://localhost:8080/?browser=' +
        browser +
      '">'
    );
    </script>
  `.replace(/^\s+/gm, '').trim());
  res.end();
  // get out on first launch as bootstrap
  server.close();
})
  .listen(0, () => {
    // to simplify this demo / for demo sake
    // redirect OS default browser here:
    const {port} = server.address();
    console.log(`http://0.0.0.0:${port}/`);
  });
```

The `server.js` example:

```js
const {parse} = require('url');
const server = require('http').createServer((req, res) => {
  const {query: {browser}} = parse(req.url, true);
  res.write(`
    <!doctype html>
    <h1>Hello ${browser}!</h1>
  `.replace(/^\s+/gm, '').trim());
  res.end();
})
  .listen(8080);

// for demo sake (stops in 5 seconds)
setTimeout(() => { server.close() }, 5000);
```

Now, if you save these files loclaly you can run both via `node server.js & node detect.js` so that detect will detect and close and *server* will keep going ... change the `server.js` with anything you like or change the `detect.js` rediret to any sit eyou like.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out
https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-default-browser

From the Readme

```
How it works
Windows:
checks registry value HKCU\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet
Linuxes:
reads the output of xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/http
OS X:
delegated to default-browser-id from Sindre Sorhus
```

Comment: that's how it works, not necessarily how it can be done, specially with non mainstream platforms  this is a good source of info regardless, but the solution can be better organized, imho, see my answer 